# Как удалить куки через заданное время (jquery.cookie.js)?

Tags: jquery, cookie

На сайте используется jquery.cookie.js.
В строке

```
$.cookie("cookiename", dateEnd, {expires: 1});
```

указывается время жизни куки (1 - 1 день).
Можно ли задать удаление куки не через день, два и т.д.,
а допустим, через час?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы не прочесть [документацию](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) к плагину?

> Define lifetime of the cookie. Value
>   can be a Number which will be
>   interpreted as days from time of
>   creation **or a Date object**. If omitted,
>   the cookie becomes a session cookie.

[А давай и я примеры за тебя поищу!](https://www.google.com/?q=jquery+cookie+expires+hour#newwindow=1&q=jquery+cookie+expires+hour)